# Angular img tag src conditional

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image

i have img1.png, img2.png, img3.png and img4.png, how to add one of these images in src based in a condition

```
<img src ="if a===1 then img1.png if a ===2 then img2.png if a === 3 then img3.png if a ===4 then img4.png>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to to this is set the image source dynamically in your component .ts file.

Your template

`<img [src]="image">`

In your component

`get image() { return ...add your logic to figure out what image to show}`

Comment: this is also a good tactic.

Comment: I like this answer. Both ways will work.

Comment: This looks nice, but it really isn’t I’m afraid. It’s not a good idea to call functions from your template like this.

Comment: what is the problem with calling functions from your template? getter functions are triggered by angular change detection, and run 1 time for each change.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

run the condition in a function, and use interpolation on the src= like:

> ```
>     src={{imageVariable}}
>
> in the ts part call
> useImagae(){
> if(a === 1)
> this.imageVariable = "img1.png"
> }
> ```